# What is transpose multiplier and forward multiplier?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, matlab, computational-mathematics

For linear system X = A*s, we define the forward and transpose multiplies Af and At as follows:

```
Af = @(s) A*s;  
At = @(s) A'*s;
```

I want to know what is forward and transpose multiplies ? And what is the functionality of forward and transpose multiplies?

Comment: I don't understand the question, you have defined the quantities involved above?

Comment: @copper.hat, no I did not define it, I got it from OMP Sparse Recovery code written by Stephen Becker

Comment: @copper.hat, I just do not understand why he defined something like this in his Matlab Code to do calculation.

Comment: Maybe the code needs a function as parameter?

Comment: @copper.hat     What does this expression mean just in math area or linear algebra area? I do not think it it related to the function

Comment: The are called anonymous functions. The first defines a function that takes a parameter $s$ and returns $A*s$. (It also takes the closure of the free variables, so if you change $A$ subsequently, it does not affect the functions.) The second is similar, but uses the complex conjugate of $A$ instead.

Comment: @copper.hat, I do not think you are right

Comment: @copper.hat, Is A equal to Af or Ar? I mean the value

Comment: They are related, $A$ is a matrix. Af is a function that computes the value of A*s. But they are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines define two [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) in terms of $A$.

Both functions take matrices as their inputs (presumably, the intent is to use them on column vectors).  For a matrix x, the input `Af(x)` returns the same thing as `A*x`, and the input `At(x)` returns the same thing as `A'*x`.

For example, you can try the following commands in the command line to see how it all works:

```
A=[1 1 0; 0 1 1; 0 0 1];
Af = @(s) A*s;  
At = @(s) A'*s;
x = [1; 0; 0];
Af(x)
At(x)
```

The last two lines should produce the outputs

```
1
0
0
```

and

```
1
1
0
```

Comment: You're welcome!